# How to use a python script on a django website

Tags: python, django, html

Am new to Django but want to learn it and have covered pretty much the basics on the Django website. 
Here is my problem:
I have written a python script which presently works in the python shell, but I want to make use of the script on my web. So that when a user goes to my website and provides the neccesary input, clicks submit, the webpage links the input to the python script(which already has input fields like those on the webpage),  and the python script runs according to the input given by the user, evaluates it and prints the result of the script on the webpage. 
Please help me out guys, counting on you all.
But feel free to suggest other frameworks that could best serve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you would be better off moving the contents of your script into a django view and executing it after your form has been validated.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/?from=olddocs#using-a-form-in-a-view

Answer (score 0):

In your view, you can get the form data using request object. You can pass the form values to your script and send output to your response object.

It seems you didn't completely understand how django works. Please go through the tutorial again.

Comment: I really appreciate the way you have broken it down into bits, but could you actually give me the links to the specific pages where the concepts you have mentioned were discussed or problem put me through by helping me with the codes to get them done. Thanks in advance